# Title automatic add (-)

Tags: css, text, title

I have problem this my little widget, and I do not understand, how do I fix it?

[image: Screenshot]:

Comment: Try: hyphens:none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [This Guide](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/) that may help you on css-tricks. By using `hyphens:none;` you can prevent the text from hyphenating.

Comment: It's Work, Thanks. :)

Comment: Consider the initial `hyphens: manual` instead, so that you can still add hyphens manually.